# AWS Athena - What happens when you add new files to S3 folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have a sample working where I put a file in S3.
What I'm confused about is what happens when I add new CSV files (with the same format) to that folder.

Are they instantly available in queries? Or do you have to run Glue or something to process them? So for example, what if set up a Lambda function to extract a new CSV every hour, or even every 5 minutes to that same S3 directory.

Does Athena actually load the data into some database somewhere in order to do fast performing queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your table is not partitioned or you add a file to an existing partition the data will be available right away.

However, if you constantly add files you may want to consider partition your table to optimize query performance, see:

- [Table Location in Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/tables-location-format.html)
- [Partitioning Data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html)

Athena itself doesn't have any caching, any query will hit the S3 location of the table.

Comment: Thanks, I made need to partition by date